# How can i extract all the frames automatic from a MOV video files using ffmpeg?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FFLib;

namespace Lightnings_Extractor
{


    class FFlibMov
    {


        public FFlibMov()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Im using the ffmpeg wrapper for c# I have referenced FFLib.dll
Downloaded the wrapper from here : http://vbffmpegwrapper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=default

What I want is to extract all the frames from a movie file MOV type to the hard disk. So in the end of the process I will have many jpeg/bmp or any type of images of all the frames on the hard disk.

How can I do it ?